# @Timed annotation in spring metrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, micrometer

I use `@Timed` annotation on String Boot rest controller and it works fine. Method from controller calls method from service which is also annotated with `@Timed`.

However, this annotation on method in subsequent service bean doesn't work (I don't see results in `/metrics`). Why is it happening? Could it be fixed?

Comment: are you using Dropwizard `@Timed` or something else?

Comment: it's from io.micrometer.core.annotation

Comment: although I imported 'org.springframework.metrics:spring-metrics:latest.release'

Answer (score 11):

As per [Support for @Timed in any Spring-managed bean #361](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/361) you can get this behaviour by registering [`TimedAspect`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/aop/TimedAspect.java) manually.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AutoTimingConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
    return new TimedAspect(registry);
  }
}
```

Do note that as per jkschneider comment in #361:

> We can revisit application of @Timed via AOP or a BPP in Boot 2.1, depending on how the community reacts to the feature.

Comment: But how to make it works? I'm getting ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around error and have no luck to fix it...

Comment: @user_x you are missing AspectJ dependencies needed by `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. You can add `spring-boot-starter-aop` as a dependency.

Comment: @user_x verify that aspect is applied during runtime e.g. by looking at the stack trace for `TimedAspect`.

Comment: @user_x also take a look at TimedAspect code to see the metric name (e.g. `method.timed` vs `@Timed("myname").`

Comment: if aspect hasn't applied during runtime - then what to do? :)
I don't think it's 'naming' issue. I set name in service method with the same style as for controller method.

Comment: @user_x I confirmed the above configuration works with a sample: https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/timed-annotation although I found some other issue with controllers: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/780

Comment: @JohnnyLim thanks, will check later, I see you use slightly upper spring version, may be this is the cause.

Comment: Anybody knows if this works out of the box with CompletableFutures? I'm getting some weird results, too low.