# Is there a way to capture the Micrometer @Timed annotation into the Prometheus metrics store/registry?

Tags: spring, prometheus, metrics, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I want to capture the data from Micrometer's @Timed annotation into the Prometheus metrics store/registry. I can't find any explanations on how to do this online.

These are the versions I am using:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.4.RELEASE' // This already includes micrometer I believe
compile "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.1.4'
```

I'm trying to time a repository call:

```
interface HouseRepository { 

@Timed
@Query(some long complicated query)
House deleteByAddressAndLastModifiedBefore(
    Address address,
    Instant instant
)

}
```

How do I do this? I tried adding some different configs to the @Timer annotation, such as:

```
  @Timed(description = 'this.is.my.metric', value = 'my.metric', extraTags = ['my.metric.name', 'test'])
```

But I don't see my output in Prometheus (/prometheus).

Surely, this is possible to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Timed annotation in spring metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749391/timed-annotation-in-spring-metrics)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [micrometer docs](http://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_the_timed_annotation):

> Micrometer’s Spring Boot configuration does not recognize @Timed on arbitrary methods.

To enable the `@Timed` annotation to work as you would like it to, you probably need to configure a `TimedAspect` bean.

```
@Configuration
public class TimedConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
      return new TimedAspect(registry);
   }
}
```

> Applying `TimedAspect` makes `@Timed` usable on any arbitrary method.

Comment: You also need spring-aspects dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects/. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63233672/432903