# How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-micrometer, aspectj-maven-plugin

Hey guys I am getting the following error on Spring-Boot when running an App I have:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'timedAspect' defined in class path resource [com/project/service/config/MicrometerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect]: Factory method 'timedAspect' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect]: Factory method 'timedAspect' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint
    at io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect.<init>(TimedAspect.java:73)
    at com.adviqo.expertmanagementservice.config.MicrometerConfig.timedAspect(MicrometerConfig.java:22)
    at com.adviqo.expertmanagementservice.config.MicrometerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0ffdf17.CGLIB$timedAspect$2(<generated>)
    at com.adviqo.expertmanagementservice.config.MicrometerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0ffdf17$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2d8e3feb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.adviqo.expertmanagementservice.config.MicrometerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0ffdf17.timedAspect(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 54 more
```

**POM FILE:**

```
<dependencies>
        <!--Metrics-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            <version>${io.micrometer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-stackdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${io.micrometer.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I am not entirely sure why this happens. I suspect that maybe a dependency is missing but as I am new to spring boot, I dont really understand what the error message states exactly.
Does any of you have an idea why this error occurs? If so, could you please let me know how you came into this conclusion?
Let me know if I should post my pom file. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your pom file

Comment: Are you using spring aop? what is the spring version?

Comment: no, thats the weird thing I am not using aop @ArghyaSadhu
spring version: 2.2.7.RELEASE

Comment: Could you show the code (or at least the declaration & method signatures) from `com/project/service/config/MicrometerConfig`? That's the class from where the AOP stuff seems to be referenced.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `ProceedingJoinPoint` is available in the `org.aspectj:aspectjweaver` dependency, which is included in the `org.springframework:spring-aspects` dependency.

To resolve the issue, include the following dependency in your POM file --

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also you can use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa which brings spring-aspect.

Answer (score 2):

Adding [spring-boot-starter-aop](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop) in my spring boot application solved the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```